# Call method in Eclipse IDE like bluej

Tags: java, eclipse, bluej

The only thing I even slightly like about bluej is the fact that you can call methods without having a String[] args bit.  Is there any equivalent in eclipse ide?  I am in a computer science class so we don't always make full pieces of code, it is normally writing methods to return things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for: [Eclipse Scrapbook](http://pure-essence.net/2008/12/11/eclipse-run-java-code-easily/)

Pretty simple tutorial and great if you are just looking to test some snippets of code.

Comment: I've been using Eclipse for quite a while, and never knew that. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Wow, awesome!  This is an awesome feature, thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the part of BlueJ that shows a canvas with each class in a square, and allows you to right+click the object to create an instance of that class, and provide parameters, then I don't think you'll find one for Eclipse unless there is a plugin somewhere I couldn't find on Google :)

adback03 might have a good alternative, or you could achieve something similar but not as graphically friendly by created a new class in your project that is dedicated for testing classes.

Later in the text "Objects First with Java" you will start learning to use the Java test framework. You will instantiate and test objects using a test class. This is how you will do it after class, I know it's not as visually pleasing but you should probably start getting used to it :)